# Easily (GUI?) creating custom VS project template?

Tags: visual-studio, project-template

Is there an easy way to create custom project templates?
I did a quick google, but it seems I have to fuzz around with all kinds of zip files, xml documents etc..

What I ultimately want to make is something like the Empty Solution template, but with some directories and custom projects already in place.

I want this because it would make my life slightly more comfortable, but it's not important enough to learn all the gritty details about how the project templates work...

**EDIT**
[Schooner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614398/easily-gui-creating-custom-vs-project-template/614416#614416) answers my question. But if anybody has a more general answer, that would be great too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make new empty solutions and save them to a template folder of your own.  You can then copy them as needed and rename them when needed for a new real project.  Might be faster than trying to figure out true templating in VS.

Comment: Does it matter if it is cheap if it works?  I try and not waste time solving isues that don't move work forward.  Quick and dirty is sometimes best unless you have free time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at WarmuP (https://github.com/chucknorris/warmup).  I've found some success in using it.  It can use github and token replacement to create a solution structure for you from a "template"